# Pushviewcontroller animation from right to left

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am creating an interactive iPad App, that is using a lot of *Swiping*. I want when swiping from right to the left and the animation also should go from right till left is. the other way from left till right is possible:

**Example swipe left to right, call method**:
 `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];` 
**Result: GOOD!** Animation from left to right, and that is correct. But now the other way....

**Question:** How can I animate to go to a other UIViewController from right till left?

**Posible solution?:** I tried to use PopViewController but I don't always want to return to the previous ViewController. Is there a way to manipulate the previous ViewController

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass your view which you want to animate in the function below. And it will animate the view from left to right. Push the view controller

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];
```

and then pass the viewcontroller's view in the function below

```
-(void) imgSlideInFromLeft:(UIView *)vew 
{
     CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
     transition.duration = 0.4;
     transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
     transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
     transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
     transition.delegate = self;
     [vew.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It works! Its a pitty that I have a back background while doing the animation. Ik looks like its flashing. But THANK YOU!